# Horizontally and vertically flexbox css not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to center the below HTML vertically and horizontally but it's not working vertically, only horizontally. Please could someone help explain why it's not working?

```
<body>
    <header class="nav">
        <img class="icon" src="./img/eiffel-tower.svg" attr="Icon made by Monkik from www.flaticon.com">
        <a class="home-anchor" href="./index.html">Learn</a>
    </header>
        <div class="quiz-container">
            <p class="word-to-conjugate" id="randomWord"></p>
            <input type="text" id="userGuess">
            <button class="answer-button" id="checkAnswer">Answer</button>
        </div>
</body>
```

My CSS using flexbox trying to center the quiz horizontally and vertically

```
.quiz-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.word-to-conjugate {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.answer-button {
    background-color: #505FDF;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an executable example and be mroe specific about what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have nothing making the quiz-container aligning vertically.

See example below, trick is to add a wrapper around your quiz element which aligns it vertically. Lastly, be sure to set the height of `html`, `body` and wrapper element to 100%;

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.quiz-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.word-to-conjugate {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.answer-button {
    background-color: #505FDF;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="nav">
        <img class="icon" src="./img/eiffel-tower.svg" attr="Icon made by Monkik from www.flaticon.com">
        <a class="home-anchor" href="./index.html">Learn</a>
    </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="quiz-container">
            <p class="word-to-conjugate" id="randomWord"></p>
            <input type="text" id="userGuess">
            <button class="answer-button" id="checkAnswer">Answer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Right! Thanks, it's working now. Although with my nav I've set the height to 90% otherwise it doesn't appear center but further down because of the nav height.

Comment: @SeanBoulanger - you can also set your nav to `position: absolute`, and keep `height: 100%` on body, html and wrapper elements to keep vertical alignment perfectly centered. You might need to add `left:0; right:0;` to your nav and specify its `height` to keep it full width at the top of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

`p`, `input`, `button` are already centered with respect to their parent: `.quiz-container`

Maybe you are looking for it to be centered with respect to the complete screen/viewport. In that case you need to set the `min-height` of `html`, `body` and `quiz-container` to `100%`.

Now `.quizcontainer` has 100% height and its children will be centered 
both vertically and horizontally.

```css
body, html{
  min-height: 100%; /*add this*/
}
 .quiz-container {
  min-height: 100%; /*add this*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.word-to-conjugate {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.answer-button {
  background-color: #505FDF;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="nav">
      <img class="icon" src="./img/eiffel-tower.svg" attr="Icon made by Monkik from www.flaticon.com">
      <a class="home-anchor" href="./index.html">Learn</a>
  </header>
      <div class="quiz-container">
          <p class="word-to-conjugate" id="randomWord"></p>
          <input type="text" id="userGuess">
          <button class="answer-button" id="checkAnswer">Answer</button>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```